# arrays of functions to one function(logical conjunction)

Tags: javascript

I have a array of functions which each of them returns boolean value:

`(data, filter) => boolean`

(depending on whether the parameter meets the condition stored in the function) and I would like to create method which dynamically merge all of them and return one function as logical conjunction:

`function1 && function2 && function3 && ...`

I was trying to use `&=` operator, but it didn't work:

```
  method(expressions) {
    let result;
    expressions.forEach(exp => {
      result &= exp;
      console.log(result);
    });
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: I don't know what each of these functions does, but have you thought about using Promise.all?

Comment: with your `data` and `filter` `expressions.map(e => e(data, filter)).every(result => result)`

Comment: @RPasha, this is exactly what I want! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this kind of array of functions:

```
const expressions = [
    (data, filter) => true,
    (data, filter) => false,
    ...
];
```

You can evaluate them all like this (`d` and `f` are assumed to be the values to pass to each function):

```
expressions.every(exp => exp(d, f))
// or
expressions.reduce((res, exp) => res && exp(d, f), true)
```

[`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) will stop as soon as any function returns `false`. You can use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to test the opposite, whether *any* function returns `true`. [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) loops through all expressions instead and is closer to what you were attempting; in this particular example it's not very useful, but can be helpful if you need to combine your return values in other ways.